# My version of chrome is not the latest but it says it is

Tags: google-chrome

I was just working with my brother's chrome, he is a new user and his version is 34.xxxxxxx and I went to check what mine was as they were displaying some things on a website differently, mine says it is Version 30.0.1599.101 m and that it is up to date? I am assuming that my brother who has just installed Chrome has the up to date version and my should be 34.xxxxxx why does mine not say this?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it?

Comment: Actually, the latest version of Chrome is, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history), 35.0.1916.116. Most cases of a program saying that it's up to date when it's not can be explained by the program not receiving an update notice from the central servers, because the newer versions use a different set of protocols to communicate with the servers. You can always update manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 35 is the current version.  If it isn't updating, go to chrome.google.com and download the installer.  It will place the latest version over the top of your current install.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My Chrome 34 is waiting to update on restart.

Comment: I find I'm having the identical problem with 51.0.2704.63 in 2016, yes, I can manually update, but that doesn't explain why it checks and says the program is up to date when it isn't, nor why it refuses to do an update. Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with this for a while on my mac. I had tried many times to follow [the directions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en) to uninstall and reinstall, but it was still the same version. The key mistake? When I would "uninstall" I would follow the directions and put Chrome from my Applications folder in the trash. What I didn't do was remove the shortcut on my dock, so it was opening it from the trash!

**Make sure to remove any shortcuts you use to open Chrome when uninstalling!**